# bzip2 in path but not found while installing R

Tags: r, bzip2

I was trying to install `R` version `3.5.3`. When I configured it failed at the step of `bzip2`. the last few lines of the verbose is as below:

```
checking for BZ2_bzlibVersion in -lbz2... yes
checking bzlib.h usability... yes
checking bzlib.h presence... yes
checking for bzlib.h... yes
checking if bzip2 version >= 1.0.6... no
checking whether bzip2 support suffices... configure: error: bzip2 library and headers are required
```

I checked that `bzip2` is in the path and its version is `1.0.8`.

```
which bzip2
/usr/local/bin/bzip2

bzip2 --version
bzip2, a block-sorting file compressor.  Version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019.

   Copyright (C) 1996-2019 by Julian Seward.

   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms set out in the LICENSE file, which is included
   in the bzip2 source distribution.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   LICENSE file for more details.

bzip2: I won't write compressed data to a terminal.

bzip2: For help, type: `bzip2 --help'.
```

Why couldn't `R` find `bzip2` even it is in the path? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same issue and find the solution with this [article](https://oguya.ch/posts/2017-03-18-building-R-on-rhel-6/).

The solution is to set the LDFLAGS and the CFLAGS for bzip2 and tell to R to configure with static libs:

```
export LDFLAG="-L/usr/local/bzip2/lib"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/bzip2/include"
./configure --enable-R-static-lib
```